# How to get rid of color behind text on Word for Mac?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, colors

The background of every text is yellow and I just would like to have it normal. It's not highlighted or the text color. The page color option is grey, so I can't click on that. The image is an example of what it looks like. When there is more text, more yellow and the rest of the page is just white like normal, it's just behind the text.

[image]

Comment: You should be able to change the background color of the text back to white. If you cannot, please post an example Word document.

Comment: I cannot, see the example above. In any other word document it's not a problem, only in this template.

Comment: Template or document? You might have changed the text style, but that shouldn't stop you from changing it back. You would best post the document. If you cannot, storing the document as `rtf` and then back to `doc(x)` can sometimes get rid of some artifacts.

Comment: If you could upload an example file this would be easier to solve, otherwise we have no way of knowing what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that's a Character Style with a yellow Pattern foreground shading set at about a 30% opacity. It's not a paragraph style because white background is showing between lines. If it was a paragraph style setting the entire block would be yellow.

The line spacing is also sightly more than 1, probably 1.15. If it was set to single spacing the shading would bleed into the space between lines.

Unless a custom VBA routine was used to set a specific RGB value on a custom highlight, the default highlight colors have a lot more vibrance and clarity ... so I'd also rule out it being a highlight.

To verify this, from the Home tab (I assume you are using Office for the Mac 2016 or later) open the Styles pane. The button looks like this:

[image]

Select one of the words with this yellow shading and check its Style Name.

Assuming I am correct, then Modify the Style to how you want it to look, OR ... select the entire paragraph(s) of text and change the Style of text to something else, such as Body Text or Normal.